# Changing replication snapshot folder, require re-snapshot?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

We have SQL Server 2012 SP2 running on Windows Server 2012.

We need to change the snapshot folder for all (including default) transaction replication publications.

I have read that this means the replication needs to be re-initialized?

Why is the case? If I update table `msdb.dbo.MSdistpublishers` with the new working_directory then I can't see why the replication should need to be re-initialized?

Any recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change in this way

```
exec sp_changepublication  @publication
@property='snapshot_in_defaultfolder'
@value='0'
@force_invalidate_snapshot=0,--always remmeber that
@force_reinit_subscription=0--always remmeber that

exec sp_changepublication  @publication
@property='alt_snapshot_folder'
@value='C:\your_dir'
@force_invalidate_snapshot=0,--always remmeber that
@force_reinit_subscription=0--always remmeber that
```